# Convert Java ArrayList To JS Array in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, arraylist

I need to know is there any way to convert Java ArrayList to Array in JavaScript.

This is the class file

```
public class SubMenuDto {

    private String subMenuName;

    private Integer subMenuOrder;

    private String menuLink;

    public SubMenuDto() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public SubMenuDto(String subMenuName, Integer subMenuOrder, String menuLink) {
        super();
        this.subMenuName = subMenuName;
        this.subMenuOrder = subMenuOrder;
        this.menuLink = menuLink;
    }

    /**
     * @return the subMenuName
     */
    public String getSubMenuName() {
        return subMenuName;
    }

    /**
     * @param subMenuName the subMenuName to set
     */
    public void setSubMenuName(String subMenuName) {
        this.subMenuName = subMenuName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the subMenuOrder
     */
    public Integer getSubMenuOrder() {
        return subMenuOrder;
    }

    /**
     * @param subMenuOrder the subMenuOrder to set
     */
    public void setSubMenuOrder(Integer subMenuOrder) {
        this.subMenuOrder = subMenuOrder;
    }

    /**
     * @return the menuLink
     */
    public String getMenuLink() {
        return menuLink;
    }

    /**
     * @param menuLink the menuLink to set
     */
    public void setMenuLink(String menuLink) {
        this.menuLink = menuLink;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SubMenuDto [subMenuName=" + subMenuName + ", subMenuOrder=" + subMenuOrder + ", menuLink=" + menuLink
                + "]";
    }

}
```

and i have a ArrayList with objects of above class.

So in JSP i need to create a array like following using ArrayList i have created in controller level.

```
var applicationShortCuts = [
    { value: 'subMenuName', data: 'menuLink' },
    { value: 'subMenuName2', data: 'menuLink2' },
    { value: 'subMenuName3', data: 'menuLink3' },
  ];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use any JSON libraries like `JackSon` or `gson` to convert your `JAVA object` into `JSON` (The format you provided in example is a JSON Format.)

E.g using GSON library :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jScriptArray = gson.toJson(<ArrayList of Obj>);
System.out.println(jScriptArray);
```

for more info please visit : https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide